# When I tried to move our whole data to new server we are facing this issue

Tags: hibernate, solr, oracle11g, jboss, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking to find the cause for this error. We are migrating the data to the new server, and while migrating we are facing this issue. What can I try?

```
  08:05:03,469 ERROR [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: Error during crash recovery: java:/cpWebDatasource (Could not create connection): javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection 
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:461)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:398)
            at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl.open(XAResourceRecoveryImpl.java:343)
            at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryImpl.java:170)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jbossatx.jta.XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.java:51) [jbossjts-integration-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:516) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:182) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:743) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:854)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
            at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:406)
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:525)
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:255)
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:153)
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:133)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:444)
            ... 8 more
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:571)
            at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:661)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:202)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:340)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out, socket connect lapse 127203 ms. /10.111.73.5 1521 0 1 true
            at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:233)
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)
            ... 24 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:646) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
            at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
            at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:99)
            at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:77)
            at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:192
```

Comment: Your new server has a different firewall connection?

Comment: we even went through it , but still facing the issue

Comment: Start by finding out _where_ the issue is. Can you connect to the server using `curl` or `telnet` on the command line? If that doesn't work, it's a connectivity issue between the two hosts / firewalled off. Is the IP address still correct after moving servers? Does the syslog / apparmor / selinux logs say anything if enabled?